# Going through 2D list with a way of snake

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have a 2D square list of size `n`. My purpose is to run through it with a shape of a snake. For example:

```
array = [[1, 2, 3],
         [4, 5, 6],
         [7, 8, 9]]
```

For this case result should be `[1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 5]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def spiral_array(arr):
        if arr == []: return []
        up = 0; left = 0
        down = len(arr)-1
        right = len(arr[0])-1
        direct = 0  # 0: go right   1: go down  2: go left  3: go up
        res = []
        while True:
            if direct == 0:
                for i in range(left, right+1):
                    res.append(arr[up][i])
                up += 1
            if direct == 1:
                for i in range(up, down+1):
                    res.append(arr[i][right])
                right -= 1
            if direct == 2:
                for i in range(right, left-1, -1):
                    res.append(arr[down][i])
                down -= 1
            if direct == 3:
                for i in range(down, up-1, -1):
                    res.append(arr[i][left])
                left += 1
            if up > down or left > right: return res
            direct = (direct+1) % 4

array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

print(spiral_array(array)) # [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 5]
```

source: https://leetcode.com/problems/spiral-matrix/

Comment: welcome, hope it helps you  If any of it doesn't make sense or if you need more information to understand how and why it works, feel free to comment or ask more.